# How should we tag Donkey Kong Country questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, canon

*Mario* is a big series.

There are a few sub-series, and six questions on this site are on the [donkey-kong](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong) tag. Of those six, five are about the *Donkey Kong Country* series of games.

Donkey Kong the character, along with Cranky, Funky, and Diddy Kong, is clearly part of the Mario universe; Donkey Kong's father (now Cranky Kong) was first in *Donkey Kong* as the villain who is fought by Jumpman, an old name for Mario. Now, he appears in almost all spin-off *Mario* games, and Diddy Kong is frequently in them, too. However, I don't know if the *Donkey Kong Country* games are part of the Mario universe. I cannot think of any connections outside of characters.

**Should these questions have the [super-mario-brothers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-brothers) tag?**

Comment: If anything, they're part of the Nintendo universe. Not a very useful comment, but still wanted to point it out.

Comment: Also why the one downvote? I know we're not really supposed to discuss retagging in Chat so I'm doing it here, so what's bad about the question?

Comment: Maybe they disagreed on the super-mario-brothers tag thingy?

Comment: I think the way to look at it is that that they are separate series that exist within the same fictional universes and sometimes intersect. Just like how you wouldn't tag a Doctor-Strange question with Thor just because they are both Marvel

Answer (score 9):

Questions about games that do not involve Mario or Luigi (or their evil doppelgangers) should not be tagged [super-mario-brothers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-brothers).  The characters of Mario and Donkey Kong originated in the same game, and there are plenty of instances where they appear together.  However, their is essentially no continuity to the Mario Brothers or Donkey Kong games, so it makes no sense to classify a Kong game without the Mario as part of the Super Mario Brothers series (or Mario Brother "universe").  Doing so would be rather like tagging all questions about xenomorphs with the [predator-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predator-series), because the two alien types appear in a bunch of games together.